# How to specify a function with flexible domain but same range?

Tags: notation, proof-writing

As an example, I could be interested in functions that operate on $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{R}^2$. One way to say this is "all functions $f:\mathbf{R} \to \{0,1\}$ and all functions $f: \mathbf{R}^2 \to \{0,1\}$." The more domains I want to specify, the more I have to say. Is there a more elegant way to consider all of these functions that have many domains?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}$, with $n\leq2$ be a function such that $\dots$